# VBA to set AutoFilter and filter selected columns

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to have AutoFilter applied to all data and then filter out all cells except 'Blanks" in column C. It selects all data on the worksheet for the first line but then gives me a run-time error - 'Named argument not found'.

```
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="blanks"
```

I would like the sheet to AutoFilter and filter column C to only show Blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rows("1:1").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Implicit late binding strikes again! `ActiveSheet` is an `Object`, not a `Worksheet` - any member calls you make directly against it, are inherently late-bound. That is, they can only be resolved at run-time, and you get zero compiler or IDE assistance when writing the code.

If you declared a `Worksheet` object:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

...and assigned it to the `ActiveSheet`:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

...then tried to invoke its [`AutoFilter` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofilter):

```
ws.AutoFilter
```

...you'd quickly notice something is off: `Worksheet.AutoFilter` isn't a *method*, but a *property* (and it's `Nothing` if filtering is off). You mean to use the [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) *method*.

Working with `Selection` will work, but will be just as late-bound as working with `ActiveSheet`.

Work with a `Range` instead - `CurrentRegion` just happens to be exactly that!

```
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
```

And now when you type the <kbd>Space</kbd> after that member call, you'll get *parameter quick-info* showing you what the parameters are - note that `Field` and `Criteroa1` are respectively the first and second parameters in the member's signature - this means the named arguments are actually redundant / the parameter names and the `:=` operators can be omitted, and the values passed normally:

[image: yay intellisense!]

```
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 3, "blanks"
ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="blanks" '<~ exactly equivalent to the above
```